# SELECTing data from database in vb and outputting data into label

Tags: sql, vb.net, error-handling

I have the following code which SELECTs data from a database and outputs a value to a label on the form:

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click


        Dim strConn As String = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("yourConnectionString").ToString()
        Dim sql As String = "SELECT aid FROM tbl_RAPA WHERE username=@username"
         Dim conn As New Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(strConn)
        Dim objDR As Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader
        Dim Cmd As New Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand(sql, conn)


        Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", User.Identity.Name)
        conn.Open()
        objDR = Cmd.ExecuteReader(System.Data.CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)
        While objDR.Read()
            Label1.Text = objDR("aid")
        End While
    End Sub
```

However, if the value in the database is empty, the program runs into an error. Is there a way for me to do this so the program just returns an empty value rather than crashing?

The error message i am given is `System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'System.DBNull' to type 'System.Windows.Forms.Label'.'` on the line `Label1.Text = objDR("aid")`

Comment: And what is the error message you get? On which line in the above code?

Comment: By the way, you tagged this question with ms-access, but the code above uses the classes for Sql Server. These classes cannot work with an ms-access database. So what is really your database?

Comment: Whatever error is thrown, why not check for it?

Answer (score 1):

Database objects generally need to be closed and disposed. `Using...End Using` blocks will do this for you even if there is an error.

Since you are only expecting one piece of data you can use `.ExecuteScalar` which provides the first column of the first row of the result set. This method returns an object.

Try to always use the the `.Add` method with `Parameters`. See http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/
and
https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/
and another one:
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/195937/addwithvalue-performance-and-plan-cache-implications
Here is another
https://andrevdm.blogspot.com/2010/12/parameterised-queriesdont-use.html
 I had to guess at the database type so, check your database for the real value.

Don't update the User Interface until after the connection is closed and diposed. (`End Using`). I declared `aid` before the Using block so, it could be used after the block. Check if the object, `aid`, is not Nothing before adding it to the label's Text.

```
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient

Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim aid As Object
    Using conn As New MySqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("yourConnectionString").ToString),
            cmd As New MySqlCommand("SELECT aid FROM tbl_RAPA WHERE username=@username", conn)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@username", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = User.Identity.Name
        aid = cmd.ExecuteScalar
        conn.Open()
    End Using
    If Not IsNothing(aid) Then
        Label1.Text = aid.ToString
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I would add this before `While objDR.Read()` as a precaution in case your query returns no rows:

```
if objDR.HasRows
...
```

Then, to handle the null values (this is probably what you mean by empty):

```
If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(objDR.Item("aid")) Then
    Label1.Text = objDR("aid")
Else
    Label1.Text = "Null !"
End if
```

You could also use `ExecuteScalar()` if you are only expecting one record. But you would need to handle the situation where no matching record is found.